# How to insert with Eloquant a multi level entry?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's consider I have `Quizzes` that can contain `Questions` which each of them contains some `Propositions`. Therefore I have three models: `Quiz`, `Question` and `Proposition`. The propositions are linked to the questions through a pivot table that contains: `id_question`, `id_proposition`, `is_correct`.

In a Seeder, I would like to insert a dummy quiz which could be represented in YAML as follow:

```
title: A Quiz
questions: 
  - name: Animals
    content: What's the difference between a duck?
    propositions: 
      - text: The dog has two legs
        is_correct: false
      - text: One leg is both the same
        is_correct: true
      - text: Every duck has at least several teeth
        is_correct: false
```

Traditionally in Laravel you need to split each step such as:

```
 $quiz = new Quiz;
 $quiz->name = "A Quiz";

 $question = $quiz->questions()->create();
 ...
```

Is there a shorter way to hierarchically create a new entry that would look like this:

```
Quiz::create([
   'name' => 'A Quiz'
   'questions' => [
      Question::Create([
         'name' => 'Animals',
         'content' => "What's the difference between a duck?"
         'propositions' => [
            Proposition::Create(['content' => 'The dog has two legs']),
            Proposition::Create(['content' => 'One leg is both the same'])
            Proposition::Create(['content' => 'Every duck has at least several teeth'])
         ]
      ])
   ]
]
```

Comment: i just thought using saveMany(). Quiz::create($quiz)->questions()->create($question)->propositions()->saveMany( [ new Proposition(['content'=> 'value']) ] ); but stll 1 question at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just testing with static values :

```
$quiz = Quiz::create([
    'name' => 'A quiz',
])->questions()->createMany([
    ['name' => 'animals', 'content' => 'animals content'],
    ['name' => 'fruits', 'content' => 'fruits content'],
])->map(function($value, $key){
    $value->propositions()->createMany([
        ['content' => 'content 1'],
        ['content' => 'content 2'],
    ]);
});
```

i think you can set the values based on YAML index-values(something like json) with foreach